# How to add textviews to the isometric tiled map in andengine?

Tags: android, andengine

I want to add subtiltles to a isometric tiled map game in andengine,
I added follow code

```
@Override
public void onPopulateScene(Scene pScene, OnPopulateSceneCallback pOnPopulateSceneCallback) throws Exception {
    relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
    relativeLayout.setId(0);
    this.addContentView(relativeLayout, new LayoutParams(android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
    relativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    tv = new TextView(this);
    tv.setText("Actions");
    tv.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT,RelativeLayout.TRUE);
    lp.setMargins(0, 200, 0, 0);
    tv.setLayoutParams(lp);
    relativeLayout.addView(tv);
    pOnPopulateSceneCallback.onPopulateSceneFinished();
}
```

but it's not displaying textviews.

Comment: would you mind editing your post and mark your java code as "code"? just select the text and click on the "{}" button above the editor, or put 4 whitespaces before every line of code. Sorry, but I really can't see anything in your post.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=feP9LG_VgHc&feature=youtube_gdata_player please have a look once this video .i want to add subtiles for each character introuction.i tried above code for display subtile.but its not displaying on the sceen.if i add the code on loadScene method its working.but i need to OnPopulateScene method.but its not working.https://github.com/Niffy/TMXIsometricExample i want to add subtiles in this example.